# How to mock static factory method using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Following is my class where I need to mock "resourceManager.getLicenseSources(licenseId)", how this can be achieved?

```
class LicenseSourceImpl{
-----
ResourceManager resourceManager = ManagerFactory.getInstance(ResourceManager.class);
List<Source> sources = resourceManager.getLicenseSources(licenseId);
-----
}
```

Few things I've tried:

1. Mock ManagerFactory itself

   ManagerFactory mf = Mockito.mock(ManagerFactory.class);
   Mockito.when(mf.getInstance(any())).thenReturn(resourceManager);
   Mockito.when(resourceManager.getLicenseSources(LICENSE_ID)).thenReturn(sources);

This fails with `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.getName()" because "clazz" is null`

2. Mock ManagerFactory and static mock

   ManagerFactory mf = Mockito.mock(ManagerFactory.class);
   Mockito.when(mf.getInstance(ResourceManager.class)).thenReturn(resourceManager);
   Mockito.when(resourceManager.getLicenseSources(LICENSE_ID)).thenReturn(sources);

This fails with

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
```

3. Spy on factory static method
   ResourceManager resourceManager = spy(ManagerFactory.getInstance(ResourceManager.class));
   but this not mocking the factory instance and creates a new instance always

Is there a way to mock for these situations?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `Mockito.mockStatic` to mock a static method. See [Mockito javadoc](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks) on how to do it. But better design would be to avoid accessing the static factory in your class but rather have the `ResourceManager` injected, so that you can inject a regular mock in your test...

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link to see how you can mock a static method https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods

You can use

```
try (MockedStatic<ResourceManager> resourceManagerMock = Mockito.mockStatic(ResourceManager.class)) {
}
```